# Powershell MYSQL query syntax with Variable

Tags: mysql, powershell, syntax, scripting

The sqlwriterow function I sends a query and retrieves the data from the specific row I'm looking for. 
I have a problem when I send querys containing powershell variables. Now instead of writing '$id' if i type in 26 (or whatever id im looking for) I'll get the expected data back. But if I put in the variable I'll get no data back. And playing around with the formats such as taking out the quotes i'll get

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 1

I've tried all sorts of ways to formatt it
such as

```
$sqlcmd4appcheck = "use spree; select * from tasks_profiles where id = '$id'"
$sqlcmd4appcheck = "use spree; select * from tasks_profiles where id = ``$id``"
$sqlcmd4appcheck = "use spree; select * from tasks_profiles where id = ''$id''"
$sqlcmd4appcheck = "use spree; select * from tasks_profiles where id = "$id""
```

Code:

```
function sqlwriterow($args1, $args2) {
    [void][system.reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom(“C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 5.0.9\Binaries\.NET 2.0\MySQL.Data.dll”)
    $dbconnect = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlconnection
    $dbconnect.connectionString = "server=207.52.55.122;user id=spree;pwd=spr33Adm1n;database=spree"
    if (-not ($dbconnect.State -like "Open")) { $dbconnect.Open() }
    $sql = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlclient.MySqlcommand
    $sql.Connection = $dbconnect
    $sql.Commandtext = $args1
    $dataset=New-Object system.Data.Dataset
    $dataAdaptor=New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter($sql)
    $dataAdaptor.fill($dataset)
    $script:row = $dataset.tables[0].Rows[0].$args2
    $dbconnect.Close()

}


$id = 26
$sqlcmd4appcheck = "use spree; select * from tasks_profiles where id = '$id'"

sqlwriterow -args1 $sqlcmd4appcheck -args2 "app"; $app = $row
```

Comment: Is it possible you just forgot the $ sign in front of sqlcmd4appcheck?

Comment: `"use spree; select * from tasks_profiles where id = "$id""` is invalid. You'd want to do `"use spree; select * from tasks_profiles where id = <backtick>"$id<backtick>""`

Comment: BobLobLaw you were right. Now what I did, as was try instead of calling the first argument with the variable $sqlcmd4appcheck I actually wrote out the query and it ran fine. That will work fine for now. Thanks man!! Its still strange that I can't just assign the query to a constant and call that though, it works for my regular querys just not ones with variables.

Comment: OK so i now solved why it would work when putting the query in but now when calling the variable designating the query. I feel so silly. In my actual script that specific sqlwriterow call is nested in another function. I had to increase the scope of $id to be available script-wide. Incase you don't know how and your looking at this for help you call and assign the variable like this $script:id this way you have access to that variable in other functions but not outside the script.. yea lesson learned, post the WHOLE script up here, not just points i think are important! Thanks again Bob!